# I lost my German Aufenthaltstitel and travelling to Italy with an Indian passport

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, vacations

I lost my wallet, along with it my German Aufenthalstitel and student ID. Fortunately my passport and work permit are safe. I had booked a vacation to Italy for 3 days with family, and we are going by car. I plan to carry all my visa proofs, the police report, copy of my Aufenthaltstitel, my work permit and even my work contract if it helps. Do you think I will be allowed into Italy and back in to Germany? I already contacted the Ausländerbehorde, but as you know it normally takes a long time to get a reply.

Comment: What exact document are you calling "work permit"? Because your Residence Permit is also your work permit, and you claim to have lost that.

Answer (score 2):

I would not risk it.

German police operates permanent immigration checkpoints at all autobahn border crossings between Austria and Bavaria. Random immigration checks are currently relatively frequent on all other border crossing between Austria and Germany as well and also between Austria and Italy in both directions. Although many cars are just 'waved through', racial profiling is obviously used when the police decides who to pick out for a more thorough check. If you are Indian, I assume that you do not look like a North European and like it or not, it will be significant.

German police will be able to access databases to verify that you have a residence permit even if you do not carry it. Austrian or Italian police will not easily be able to do so. If you are stopped for an immigration check, you must at least expect quite a lot of hassle. The worst case is probably if you are stopped at the Italian/Austrian border and both Italy and Austria refuse you entry.